# The print function only shows the first line of the file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just want to read line by line from a file and append each line to an array. I have done it before without any problems and I do not why this time it does not work! The print function only shows the first line of the file!!
Here is my code:

```
keyword_array = []    
with open('local directory\\C0577785c.txt') as my_keywordfile:
        for keyword in my_keywordfile.readline().strip("[]").strip("'").split(","):
         keyword_array.append( keyword.strip().strip("'").lower())
         print(keyword_array)
```

Also, here is a subset of the file content:

```
C0001396    adam attack stokes
C0001396    Adam Stokes Attacks
C0001396    Adam-Stokes Attacks
C0001396    adam-stokes syndrome
C0001396    adams attack stoke
C0001396    adams stoke syndrome
C0001396    adams stokes attack
C0001396    ADAMS STOKES SYNDROME
C0001396    Adams-Stokes
C0001396    Adams-Stokes Syndrome
C0001396    Adams-Stokes; attack
C0001396    attack; Adams-Stokes
C0001396    attack; Stokes-Adams
C0001396    Attacks, Adam-Stokes
C0001396    Attacks, Stokes-Adams
C0001396    morgagni's disease
C0001396    Morgagni-Adam's Stokes syndrome
C0001396    Morgagni-Stokes-Adams
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a nested loop to read the lines of my_keywordfile.

```
for line in my_keywordfile.readlines():
    for keyword in line.strip("[]").strip("'").split(","):
```

Comment: Thanks @id0. This is exactly what I needed to enter.

Answer (score 0):

You only call readline() once, so only one line is printed.

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop you want to call .readlines() on the file object. Not readline().  readline() only returns the first line, and readlines() returns a list of lines that you can iterate over.

From the docs:

```
readlines(...) method of _io.TextIOWrapper instance
    Return a list of lines from the stream.

    hint can be specified to control the number of lines read: no more
    lines will be read if the total size (in bytes/characters) of all
    lines so far exceeds hint.
```

I would also recommend not sanitizing the row at the for loop declaration.  It think it reads a little easier if you do that inside of the for loop.

```
# ....
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as my_file:
    for raw_line in my_file.readlines():
        cleaned_data = raw_line.lower().strip("'")
        #....
```

Comment: Thanks @Kyle. But I get this error: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: readlines() returns a list and you are trying to call .strip() on a list which won't work.  I'll update my answer here.